# Vertical center aligning output in python

Tags: python-3.x, format

I know how to horizontally centre align output in python using `print("{:^8}".format("Hello W"))`
Is there some way of doing it both horizontally and vertically centre aligned?
I want to display text at exactly the **centre** of the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the terminal's dimensions with [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#querying-the-size-of-the-output-terminal). If you have the terminal height, you can print newlines for half the height, then print your line. For example:

```
import shutil

def print_line_vcentred(s):
    centre_line = int(shutil.get_terminal_size().lines/2)
    print('\n'*centre_line, s, '\n'*centre_line)

print_line_vcentred("test")
```

If you want to print multiple lines vertically centered, subtract half the number of lines from `centre_line` to offset the start of the text.